# What are good books to get into Silverlight, at an advanced level?

Tags: silverlight

I'd like to find a good, solid book, aimed at the skilled developer market, for an all round introduction to Silverlight.  What titles are the best for a developer like me, who doesn't want simplistic explanations, but clear explanations in proper programming terms of how things work, and how to get things done?

Case in point, I can't remember the title, but a book I read at a previous employer on ASP.NET 2.0 was the first I encountered to explain the request pipeline and dynamic compilation model of ASP.NET Web Site projects, in such a way that I am still impressed with the model and the explanation, after two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought this one. It seems to be what everyone has suggested. It is goes into depth for intermediate levels and advanced. If you can wade through it, I would suggest it.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/book/Pro-Silverlight-3-in-C.aspx